# Reason for the exponential speed-up expected from quantum computers

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, time-complexity, space-complexity, qubit

In quantum computers those 2 effects should be seen:

1) If an operator acts on an arbitrary QuBit Qn of a quantum system S consisting of several QuBits than we get a new quantum system S' where the amplitues of ALL QuBits have changed.

2) If an operator acts on one QuBit of a quantum system T consisting of two entangled QuBits than both QuBits are affected.

So which one of these is the reason for the exponential speed-up expected from quantum computers?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"...**which one** of these is the reason...?"*

None.

As of 2020-Q2, the so far available Q-devices operate in constant `[TIME]`, i.e. having *`O(1)`* (in)-dependency of TimeDOMAIN duration of operations on the problem-complexity, so neither the isolated assumption 1) nor the isolated assumption 2) make any difference on their own, but both are the part of the quantum Level-of-Detail observed World, as we know it, that is ( by design intrinsically ) **`Q-[PARALLEL]`**.

Actually,
 the World as we know it, is the Q-SpaceTime *continuum* itself, internally discrete in both Time and Space at such a LoD, we will never have a trouble with in any foreseeable Q-device computing, if considering The Universe not being a Q-device of it's own kind, which it obviously is **`;)`**

All happens "*now*", not one after another ( as if sequenced in some pipelined fashion ).
 <sub>( The full depth of this topic way exceeds the format of this Q/A-site. )</sub>

Sure,
pedantic and Q-orthodox users may claim a need to use some `[SPACE]`-Domain downscaling tricks due to current Q-devices limits of the physical-Q-engine, yet even these retain the `O(1)` (in)-dependence, as the asymptotic complexity (in)-dependence model of the QPU-based computing.

> **Q** : *"...the **exponential speed-up** expected from quantum computers?"*

Given the above, there is but a market-making motivation to call Q-devices "*expected*" to have
*(cit.)*: "***exponential speed-up***".

Given the target Q-device operates on *`O(1)`* scaling, all the previously known technologies are compared to a constant-Time *"processing"*.

In this context,
the category of **Speedup**
will be the way more "*showing **the better** factor of comparison*", **the worse** the original processing is (was).

The Q-device ( no matter how easy or bad the original processing was )
will be
and
will always remain a constant-Time Q-"processor"

---

### The BONUS Part :

> So,
> the *`O(1)`* Q-device will always show itself ***best*** against any worst scaling of the original problem-processing strategy, where the exponentially scaling is not our worst enemy in the Complexity ZOO.
> Similarly, **the very same Q-device** will show itself as a ***poor-neighbour* once compared to any currently known `O(1)` processing** that may and often will outperform any Q-device due to small if not missing at all initial-Setup / Result-detection / termination-Gap(s), known  as the Q-device principal add-on processing-latencies ( which do not play any significant role for the former case, where nature of the shift-of-paradigm in the field of complexity works strongly against any classical device(s) )